# Validation doesn't work (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

In `model/item.rb` I have custom validation method

```
  validate :double_dates
  after_save :double_check

  private

  def double_dates
    if Item.where(:user_id => self.user_id, :asin => self.asin, :domain => self.domain).where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today).length >= 1
      errors.add(:created_at, "no double dates")
    end
```

Validation method does work in "rails c". But, when I run two task at the same time (`rails runner "ApplicationController.rotate"` I have Item.save in rotate method) - validation stops working.

```
irb(main):044:0> i1.created_at
=> Thu, 24 Apr 2014 02:41:15 UTC +00:00
irb(main):045:0> i2.created_at
=> Thu, 24 Apr 2014 02:41:15 UTC +00:00
irb(main):046:0> i1.created_at == i2.created_at
=> false
irb(main):047:0> i1.created_at.to_time.to_i == i2.created_at.to_time.to_i
=> true
irb(main):048:0> i1.created_at.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
irb(main):049:0> i2.created_at.class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
irb(main):050:0> i1.created_at.usec => 311714 
irb(main):051:0> i2.created_at.usec => 312779
```

Any hints or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: So your main deal is you don't want to have two items with the same creation time, but you're actually having them, right?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to have two items with the same date. But, right now it almost the same time :) only usec is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem once, and guess you could actually solve this problem adding indexes to the table. Add an index to the created_at column in Items.

[Here](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations) you've got a full explanation about indexing in rails.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you mate very much. I just tested it on local machine & it looks like it did the trick. Please, let me confirm it on server after around 24 hours, after cron does his job & I'll be able to check it. Cuz, I was thinking that it won't does the trick cuz usec is different :) Again, thank you, I'll check it tomorrow & I hope it doest work & I'll accept your answer.

Comment: No problem dude! If you got any other problem in the server side just ask! But we hope you don't have any :)

Comment: Hi mate:)
Have the same stuff :) only usec is different :))) Still, thank you very much :) now I know why I have this stuff :)

Comment: Thank you mate :) your stuff + @i.created_at = Time.now.change(usec: 0) solve it :) Again, thank you very much :) Have an awesome life :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @FabKremer I was able to solve it :)

by adding `@i.created_at = Time.now.change(usec: 0)` before `Item.save` :)

Nevertheless I'm accepting his answer, cuz it'll work for most cases.